# Принцип работы archive.extract(): "NameError: name 'basestring' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x, archive

Hужно разархивировать `.rar` архив, для этого использую модуль `archive`. При попытке разархивировать возникает ошибка `NameError: name 'basestring' is not defined`.
Код:

```
from archive import extract, Archive
import os


def extract_files(directory):
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'tmp')):
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'tmp'))
    # extract(directory, os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'tmp'), safe=True)
    arch = Archive(directory)
    arch.extract(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'tmp'), safe=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    extract_files(r'C:\[PATH]\00018505007.rar')
```

Полный Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/[PATH]/TEST/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    extract_files(r'C:\[PATH]\TEST\00018505007.rar')
  File "C:/[PATH]/TEST/test.py", line 9, in extract_files
    arch = Archive(directory)
  File "C:\[PATH]\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\archive\__init__.py", line 31, in __init__
    self._archive = self._archive_cls(file, filename)(file)
  File "C:\[PATH]\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\archive\__init__.py", line 37, in _archive_cls
    if isinstance(file, basestring):
NameError: name 'basestring' is not defined
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803467/unexpected-exception-name-basestring-is-not-defined-when-invoking-ansible2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина в том, что вы используете библиотеку `archive`, что была сделана для [python2](/questions/tagged/python2) и не поддерживает [python3](/questions/tagged/python3).

Можете попробовать самостоятельно конвертировать код для поддержки [python3](/questions/tagged/python3) через утилиту `2to3`, или руками.

А `basestring` появилось в [python2](/questions/tagged/python2), и больше не поддерживается в [python3](/questions/tagged/python3), вместо этого используется `str`:

> The builtin basestring abstract type was removed. Use str instead. The
>   str and bytes types don’t have functionality enough in common to
>   warrant a shared base class. The 2to3 tool (see below) replaces every
>   occurrence of basestring with str.

---

Поискал архиваторы `rar`, что поддерживают python2/3 и нашел такой:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rarfile/

Comment: Зачем вы поменяли назад на зython 3?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, вы изменили ответ, когда я сам правил, поэтому перетерлось :) Кст, спасибо за правку )

Comment: А я думал это особенная версия cython, jython, "зython" ;)

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, :D